# Nodejs API to Solidity data transfer

Tags: solidity, nodejs, ethereumjs, ganache

I want to know that how can I transfer Nodejs API call response to Html, where for every call or response gas will be consumed by help of Solidity from the Ganache Ethereum account.

Comment: I’ve seen this on YouTube I believe.

Comment: Can you clarify with an example what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sending a POST request from HTML to backend API developed in Express js. Now when this request is successful then gas from Ganache should be deducted which I believe could be possible by Solidity. So how can I integrate all these processes?

Comment: Are you executing a transaction in the backend? Gas measures how much a transaction has to pay in fees. They are deducted immediately when executing a transaction. A pure or view function when executed outside the blockchain don't have to pay fees, so gas isn't deducted.

Comment: Then what would be a good way to create such Blockchain application where backend APIs are based upon Nodejs Expressjs with Mongodb and front-end is on Html, Css, Solidity?